# Extract the particular portion from a String

Tags: java

I have the below `String` variable

```
String s = "abc,xyz,lmn,ijk";
```

I want to extract only the portion of the **String (`i.e - 'lmn'`)**

And, Should not use in-built functions like, `SubString(), Split(), IndexOf().` But I can use `charArray()`

And this question was asked in my interview.

I tried the below code, 
But not sure how to proceed. Can any one please provide your thoughts?

```
    String s = "abc,xyz,lmn,ijk";
    int counter = 0;

    char[] ch = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
        if (ch[i] == ',') {
            counter++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with your debugger to see what is happening?

Comment: In an interview? Really, bcz it smells like homework

Comment: @rabbitguy - Do u have solution?

Comment: can you concatenate strings?

Comment: What is the input? Is that asking a specific string or the index?

Comment: @rabbitguy Most likely a FizzBuzz type question to get rid of candidates who have very little skills.

Comment: Your question is incomplete anyhow, but are you needing to break it up into the individual words or just lmn and if so, are you given the position of it?

Comment: Guys,pls provide justification for downvote

Comment: @rabbitguy - I don't know about the position of lmn, And i just want to get only lmn from the string

Comment: @Aishu so what output is expected?

Comment: So are you basically trying to implement contains()?

Comment: @rabbit guy - lmn should be the output

Comment: @aishu then just make a method that returns lmn and you are good. It doesn't matter what you do to the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "abc,xyz,lmn,ijk";
    char[] ch = s.toCharArray();
    int counter = 0;
    int place = 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < ch.length-2; i++) {
        if(ch[i] == ',') {
            counter++;
        }
        if(counter == place && ch[i] != ',') {
            System.out.print(ch[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

It prints everything after the second comma, but before the third one.

Comment: Actually, i want to get the third element from that string. In this case, it should be 'lmn', but it can be anything else

Comment: Basically, i want to get the third comma(,) position, from there i want to iterate and get the each character until i find the next comma

Comment: @Aishu Alright, I have fixed my post. If you want to print a different 3 letters, just change place. Is it acceptable now?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String s = "abc,xyz,lmn,ijk";
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
    char[] ch = s.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
        if(','==(ch[i]))
        {
            if (sb.toString().equals("lmn")) {
                System.out.println(sb.toString());
            }
            else
            {
                int length=sb.length();
                sb.delete(0, length);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            sb.append(ch[i]);
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way.

```
String s = "abc,xyz,lmn,ijk"; 
String x = "c,x"; // String to found
String r = "";

boolean coincidence = false;

int a=0; // Initial index if of the first character in x is found
int b=0; // Last index If it was possible to search for the last character of x
int c=0; // Index "iterator" on String x

char[] ch = s.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
  if(c == x.length())
    break;
  else{
    if(ch[i] == x.charAt(c) && !coincidence){
      a = i; b = i; c++;
      coincidence = true;
    }
    else if(ch[i] == x.charAt(c) && coincidence){
      b++; c++;
    }else{
      coincidence = false;
      a = 0; b = 0; c = 0;
    }
  }
}

System.out.println("String: " + s);
System.out.println("String to find: " + x);
System.out.println("Was found? " + ((coincidence)? "Yes" : "No"));

if(coincidence){
  System.out.println("Intervals indexes in String: ["+a + "," + b +"]");
  // String extration
  for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) 
    r += s.charAt(i);

  System.out.println("String extracted: " + r);
}
```